# PDFBOX extract image tiltle from PDF

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox, text-extraction

Is there any way to extract the title (caption, i.e the text situated directly under the image) from a PDF file using the PDFBox?

I tried several techniques, one of them is to create a rectangle area and to extract the text within. That works sometimes fine, but the problem there is that you get more/less from the text of the caption..

I need really some Help!! Thanks

Comment: As long as you don't have additional information on the title, you'll have to do with heuristics, and they fail ever so often.

Comment: The PDFs are book pages, that were scanned and with OCR software generated. I don't know, how can I get more information about the images and their metadata?

Comment: Ups... that sounds like a challenging task indeed, especially if there is no standard way how images and their captions are presented in those scanned books.